# Inserting an entry into a nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having trouble inserting a entry into a nested JavaScript object

This is the object where I get the entries

```
const data = {
  periods: [
    {
      decisions: [
        {
          bank: {
            name: "Team1"
          },
          bSPositionDecisions: [
            {
              totalInputRate: 1.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            },
            {
              totalInputRate: 2.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          bank: {
            name: "Team2"
          },

          bSPositionDecisions: [
            {
              totalInputRate: 5.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            },
            {
              totalInputRate: 6.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

What I have been struggling with is looping through this object and take the "totalInputRate" that matches with "name", "category" ,"type" and bank name (team1 or team2) and insert it into a another object

The output I currently have looks like this

```
bankname = { banks:
   [ { name: 'Team1',
       LOMBARD_LOANS:
        [ { 
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' },
          { 

            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' } ],

       },
     { name: 'Team2',
       LOMBARD_LOANS:
        [ { 
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' },
          { 
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' } ],

        } ],
            }
```

The output I want to create should look like this

```
bankname = { banks:
   [ { name: 'Team1',
       LOMBARD_LOANS:
        [ { 
            totalInputRate: 1.0,
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' },
          { 
            totalInputRate: 2.0,
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' } ],

       },
     { name: 'Team2',
       LOMBARD_LOANS:
        [ { 
            totalInputRate: 5.0,
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' },
          { 
            totalInputRate: 6.0,
            name: 'asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m',
            category: 'LOMBARD_LOANS' } ],

        } ],
            }
```

I tried several things but nothing seems to work any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use map, filter and reduce to create the new structure from the existing data. We have to be careful not to make any assumptions about the category of each balance sheet position, this may vary, they may not all be LOMBARD_LOANs!

So we determine a set of balance sheet position categories and group by these.

```js
const data = { periods: [ { decisions: [ { bank: { name: "Team1" }, bSPositionDecisions: [ { totalInputRate: 1.0, balanceSheetPosition: { name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight", category: "LOMBARD_LOANS", type: "ASSET" } }, { totalInputRate: 2.0, balanceSheetPosition: { name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m", category: "LOMBARD_LOANS", type: "ASSET" } } ], }, { bank: { name: "Team2" }, bSPositionDecisions: [ { totalInputRate: 5.0, balanceSheetPosition: { name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight", category: "LOMBARD_LOANS", type: "ASSET" } }, { totalInputRate: 6.0, balanceSheetPosition: { name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m", category: "LOMBARD_LOANS", type: "ASSET" } }, ] } ] } ] };

const result = { banks: data.periods[0].decisions.map(decision => {
    // Determine the set of position categories.
    const categories = [...new Set(decision.bSPositionDecisions.map(r => r.balanceSheetPosition.category))];
    // Use reduce to create the position structure.
    return categories.reduce((pos, category) => { 
        pos[category] = decision.bSPositionDecisions.filter(d => d.balanceSheetPosition.category === category).map(d => {
            return { totalInputRate: d.totalInputRate, name: d.balanceSheetPosition.name,  category: d.balanceSheetPosition.category } ;
        });
        return pos;
    }, { name: decision.bank.name } );
})};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much this seems to work. But what if i wanted to also include an array ? So it would look something like this 
{
  "banks": [
    {
      "name": "Team1",
      "LOMBARD_LOANS": [
         features: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          "totalInputRate": 1,
          "name": "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight",
          "category": "LOMBARD_LOANS"
        },
        { features: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          "totalInputRate": 2,
          "name": "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m",
          "category": "LOMBARD_LOANS"
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]

Comment: Oh sure, that's easy enough to do. Does the array exist in your source data, or are you adding it from some other variable?

Comment: Yes, I used for loops to gather the data i wanted and put them in an array. Now i want to put that into the structure you provided me. Should i post a new question with the code i have and would you help me ?

Comment: Sure thing, that might be the best approach!

Comment: Ohh thats great, let me post the question, i will provide you with the link here

Comment: Hey, could you please have a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105653/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-nested-javascript-object

Comment: did you see the question ?

Comment: Oh okay sry to bother you with this question ...but you would make my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Please use ES6

```js
const data = {
  periods: [
    {
      decisions: [
        {
          bank: {
            name: "Team1"
          },
          bSPositionDecisions: [
            {
              totalInputRate: 1.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            },
            {
              totalInputRate: 2.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          bank: {
            name: "Team2"
          },

          bSPositionDecisions: [
            {
              totalInputRate: 5.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_onsight",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            },
            {
              totalInputRate: 6.0,
              balanceSheetPosition: {
                name: "asset_bc_lombard_a_lt1m",
                category: "LOMBARD_LOANS",
                type: "ASSET"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var finalObj = data.periods[0].decisions.map(item => ({
  name: item.bank.name,
  LOMBARD_LOANS: item.bSPositionDecisions.map(loan => ({
    ...loan.balanceSheetPosition,
    totalInputRate: loan.totalInputRate
  }))
}));

console.log(finalObj);
```